# Adding the AVR Dragon's HVPP to the Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, avrdude

I would like to teach my Arduino IDE to use my AVR Dragon's HVPP (High Voltage Parallel Programming) interface to upload compiled sketches to my boards (an ATMega1284P-PU in this case, supported by `mighty1284p`).

Working setup so far:

Arduino IDE with `mighty1284p`, I added this to the boards.txt of `mighty1284p` to support my uC's internal-RC-oscillator clockrates of 1MHz and 8MHz.

`avrdude` can talk to the `m1284p` and set the fuses:

```
avrdude -c dragon_pp -P usb -p m1284p -U lfuse:w:0x62:m -U hfuse:w:0x99:m -U efuse:w:0xFF:m -U lock:w:0xFF:m
```

I can compile / check a sketch successfully, then upload the temporarily created `.hex` manually to the 1284 using the Dragon:

```
cd /var/folders/px/xmf1dygn6p5_fn1hh05c6gyr0000gn/T/build4082512148637729777.tmp/
avrdude -p m1284p -c dragon_pp -P usb -U flash:w:Fade.cpp.hex
```

This works but includes the manual step of `cd`ing into the temporary build directory and manually uplading the `.hex`.

How would I use the AVR Dragon's HVPP directly from within the Arduino IDE? I have added a section to `programmers.txt` as such:

```
dragonpp.name=AVR Dragon HVPP
dragonpp.communication=usb
dragonpp.protocol=dragon_pp
dragonpp.force=false
```

which I assumed would be correct for the above `avrdude` parameters.

Within the IDE I choose `Tools - Programmer - AVR Dragon HVPP`, the `Upload`. The debug output shows this:

```
(...correct compiling, linking and such...)
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega1284p -carduino -P/dev/tty.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:/var/folders/px/xmf1dygn6p5_fn1hh05c6gyr0000gn/T/build1852336263469118058.tmp/Fade.cpp.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 18:52:52
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/cts/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/tty.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

So the `-p` parameter is correct, but `-c` and `-P` are wrong.

Any ideas how I could add the Dragon correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the programmer settings in your part entry (shown in your other question) override the programmer settings in the programmer entry.

Just lose these lines in the part entries:

```
mighty_opt8.upload.protocol=arduino
```